# println only outputs a single input

Tags: java

Hi i'm working on a string that reads inputs and then prints them out in the cmd
After it reads out the line i also save it into a text document however it outputs the first input

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Stringtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] s = new String[10];
        for ( int i = 0; i <= 9; i++ ){
            System.out.println ( "ord" + ( i + 1 ) + "?" );
            s[i]=input.readLine();
        }
        for ( int i = 9; i >= 0; i-- ){
            System.out.println ( s[i] );
            File path = new File("ord.txt");
            PrintWriter a = new PrintWriter (path);
            a.println ( s[i] );
            a.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't see the question here

Comment: You create the printWriter in every Iteration, so you overrides the file every time

Comment: good catch @Jens. Post that as an answer and we could close this one off

Answer (score 2):

You create the PrintWriter in every Iteration, so you overrides the file every time.
Change your code to:

```
PrintWriter a = new PrintWriter (path);
for ( int i = 9; i >= 0; i-- ){
    System.out.println ( s[i] );
    File path = new File("ord.txt");
    a.println ( s[i] );
}
a.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that line outside of your for(...)

```
PrintWriter a = new PrintWriter(path)
```

What you were doing is recreating it in every iterations, so you override what was in it.

Answer (score 0):

For the asker of the question , the problem was that PrintWriter was being created for each iteration of the loop,hence in every iteration of the loop file was being rewritten.
You can test this as follows :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter("C:/abc.txt");
            writer.print("a"+i);
            writer.close();
        }
```

The abc.txt created in above case will only have a9 in it.